# Can I use variable as the comparison operator?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, conditional-statements

I want to use a variable as comparison operator. Is it possible? Something like:

```sh
x=10
y=20
t="<"
res=`expr $x $y $t`
```

or

```sh
x=10
y=20
t="-lt"
if [ $x $y $t ]; then
    ..
fi
```

Whichever approach is fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have you not just tested* it? Yes, it is possible. Shell is interpreted language. Command `test` (for which `[` is an alias) takes arguments just as any other command. Those can be variables as well.

Example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

x=10
y=20
t="-lt"

if [ $x $t $y ]; then
    echo "a"
fi

if [ $y $t $x ]; then
    echo "b"
else
    echo "c"
fi

t="-ge"

if [ $y $t $x ]; then
    echo "d"
fi
```

Output:

```
a
c
d
```

---

* Your example don't work, because you have operator (variable `$t`) after the values (variables `$x` and `$y`), not between them.

Comment: What if I want to compare decimals?